# How to add two foreign keys in the same class (table) in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working with EF project and I try to add two foreign keys but I have a problem when I do Add Migration.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeathDate { get; set; }

    public int? FatherId { get; set; }
    public int? MotherId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FatherId")]
    public virtual Person Father { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MotherId")]
    public virtual Person Mother { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes,  I get an error:

Comment: The error:  Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Person.Mother' of type 'Person'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add new information. And did you try what the exception tells you? I.e. "manually configure the relationship". You should at least do something with such a message, it's there for a reason.

Comment: Also, please use a tag that shows the EF version you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add This code in your context

````
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .HasOptional(a => a.Mother)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(a => a.MotherId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .HasOptional(a => a.Father)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(a => a.FatherId);
}

        ```
````

Comment: Thank you @RositaEsmaili, your answer have worked.